# How would I return a pointer to an allocated data structure in C?

Tags: c, memory-management

I have created a struct:

```
typedef struct _POOL
{
    int size;
    void* memory;
}Pool;
```

and have then allocated space in the system memory for that structure but would like to return a pointer to the beginning of the allocated memory. I tried just returning the variable but got an error.

```
int main(void)
{
    Pool* allocatePool(int n);
    {
        Pool *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you got? Please note, that you are defining a variable `n` with the same name as the first argument.

Comment: @MartinZabel My mistake, I get a warning "return makes integer from pointer without a cast."

Comment: You can't nest function definitions in C.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths  He does not have a function definition inside main.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Didn't even see the semi-colon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _POOL
{
    int size;
    void* memory;
}Pool;

Pool * allocatePool( int n )
{
    Pool *p = malloc( sizeof( Pool ) );

    if ( p != NULL )
    {
        p->size = 0;
        p->memory = malloc( sizeof( n ) );
        if ( p->memory != NULL ) p->size = n;
    }

    return p;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 10;
    Pool *p = allocatePool( int n );

    //...

    if ( p != NULL ) free( p->memory );
    free( p );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you explain the conditional statement within the allocatePool function, please? I'm fairly new to C and am not sure how the "->" operator works.

Comment: @user6044446 If malloc can not allocate memory it returns null pointer. So you need to checkk whether the call was successfull.

Answer (score 0):

The function `malloc` is not declared because you missed to include the respective header `stdlib.h`. Thus, the compiler assumes an implicit declaration with a return type of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    typedef struct _POOL
    {
        int size;
        void* memory;
    } Pool;

    Pool *p=(Pool*) malloc(sizeof(Pool));

    return 0;
}
```

`Here p is a pointer to the (first byte of the) allocated memory.`